# Происходит зависание при попытке устанвления соединения с сервером

Tags: c, сокет

Ниже представлю пример воспроизведения проблемы.

Проблема в том, что при попытке установки соединения с сервером, оно просто зависает при вызове функции коннекта.

Что в данном примере не так? Почему не устанавливается соединение?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UV(X) (void) ((X))
#define KODIK_API "kodikapi.com"
#define FAILED_STR_NAME(NAME) "[-] Failed " #NAME ": %s\n"
#define REPORT_ERROR_EX(NAME, ERROR) UV(fprintf(stderr, FAILED_STR_NAME(NAME), ERROR))
#define REPORT_ERROR(NAME) REPORT_ERROR_EX(NAME, strerror(errno))

int
main(void) {
    struct addrinfo ai_hints, *ai, **cai;
    int rv;
    int fds;

    UV(memset(&ai_hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo)));

    ai_hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;
    ai_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    ai_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    rv = getaddrinfo(KODIK_API, NULL, &ai_hints, &ai);

    if (0 != rv) {
        if(EAI_SYSTEM == rv) {
            REPORT_ERROR(getaddrinfo);
            return 1;
        } else {
            REPORT_ERROR_EX(getaddrinfo, gai_strerror(rv));
            return 2;
        }
    }

    cai = &ai;

    do {
        fds = socket((*cai)->ai_family, (*cai)->ai_socktype, (*cai)->ai_protocol);
        if (-1 != fds) {
            break;
        }

        REPORT_ERROR(socket);
        cai = &((*cai)->ai_next);
    } while(NULL != (*cai));

    rv = connect(fds, (*cai)->ai_addr, (*cai)->ai_addrlen);

    if (-1 == rv) {
        REPORT_ERROR(connect);
        close(fds);
        return 3;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    UV(shutdown(fds, SHUT_RDWR));
    UV(close(fds));
}
```

Comment: Спустя время падает с ошибкой таймаута.

Comment: как минимум, ты порт не устанавливаешь ни где... нужно или имя сервиса указать в `getaddrinfo()`, или просто явно задать в `connect()`...

Comment: В connect? Там же только 3 параметра. Или имеется ввиду делать копию ai_addr и указывать порт?

Comment: да, сделать копию, проверить что это адрес нужного типа (ipv4/ipv6) и установить `sin_port` в ней...

Comment: Можно ответом написать, при указании порта соединение устанавливается.

Comment: можешь сам написать... я не соберусь скорей всего...