# WSAConnect - непонятное поведение при подключении

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую строну мне думать, чтобы понять почему так происходит?

Я пытаюсь установить соединение с сайтом government.ru. Выбрал этот сайт, потому что он первый попался, который работает по **http**, а не по **https**.

1. Сооветвенно я получаю данные об IP адресах от DNS вызывая функцию getaddrinfo, в результате возвращаются три IP:

> 95:173:136:163
>
> 95:173:136:162
>
> 95:173:136:168

Теперь вызываю `WSAConnect`, первый IP всегда отрубается по таймауту, второй всегда гарантированно подключается.

При этом, когда я смотрю в гугл хроме, к какому IP он подключается, там всегда указывается именно первый IP **95:173:136:163**`.

Не понимаю, почему у меня тогда отрубается по таймауту. Код ошибки `WSAGetLastError` == `10060`.

2. И второй момент. Когда я вызываю `WSAConnect` к примеру второй раз сразу за первым для этого же сайта, то все три IP отрубаются по тайм-ауту, но, если подождать примерно минуту, то `WSAConnect` опять подключается и опять только к 95:173:136:162, то есть такое ощущение, что на сервере установлено отбивать попытки соединения чаще 1 раза в минуту.
   НО, при этом гугл хром, как то же открывает сразу хоть 10 страниц этого сайта один за другим.

PS:с другими сайтами, ну к примеру: google.ru, facebook.com, vk.com, mail.ru - никаких проблем нет.

Вот я совершенно не могу понять, в чем проблема то у меня ?

Comment: Код которым вы подключаетесь в вопрос приведите, иначе будем гадать до китайской Пасхи.

Comment: Связаный вопрос или дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301918/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: @こきん, не, там другая причина, у меня, как и я и написал соединение устанавливается, но с нюансами, так же описанными. В том примере вообще не устанавливается соединение.

Comment: @こきん, кстати у меня к kodikapi.com (109:236:85:10) - без проблем коннектится.

Comment: меня очень смущает, что айпи пишется через двоеточие. Если так выводится айпи, то что происходит с всем остальным?

Comment: @KoVadim, да не, это я просто с консоли скопировал, выводил октеты ipшника, у меня же еще ipv6 просто автоматов двоеточием разделил, тут смущаться не нужно. Со всем остальным происходит, то, что я описал. Вот интересноо Ваше мнение именно по этому поводу. Мое предварительное мнение, что это связано с настойками самого сервера обслуживабщего этот сайт, но, как гугл хром это обходит не могу понять. Может он просто один мокет создает ? Кстати интересно можно ли в гугл хроме посмотреть, сколько он сокетов на сайт создает ?

Comment: Надо запускать Wireshark и смотреть, что собственно происходит. Сравнить два случая и вперёд